# Just-in-time jobs

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the term *“just-in-time jobs”*?  Of my dictionaries, both Macmillan and Oxford have a definition of *just-in-time*.  Macmillan says that it means:

> bought, sent, or produced at the last possible time

Meanwhile, Oxford says that *just-in-time* is:

> denoting a manufacturing system in which materials or components are
>   delivered immediately before they are required in order to minimize
>   storage costs

But I still cannot ascertain the meaning of *“just-in-time jobs”* as a phrase.

Comment: http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/just-in-time-manufacturing-JIT-manufacturing   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_in_time_%28business%29

Comment: I can capture the meaning of Just-in-time, but when it goes with "Job", I cannot guess what kind of this job is.

Comment: A unit of manufacturing, one product or one batch is called a "job".

Comment: Except that if you google the phrase (just-in-time jobs) it is not about manufacturing. It is about hiring as needed instead of hiring on a seasonal schedule.

Comment: @MετάEd Nearly all of them are from a single source, which seems to use the phrase in a non-standard sense.

Comment: What is the context? I've seen _“just-in-time jobs”_ used in computer programming as well as physical manufacturing.

Answer (score 2):

"Just-in-time" is a term related to production and manufacturing, where inventory is kept to a minimum. There is no clear meaning with respect to employment, but there are two common uses: (1) From the employer's point of view, it means on-demand labor; (2) From the employee's point of view, it's a chance for immediate employment.

Answer (score 0):

I would understand "job" here to mean a "piece of work", a "task".

So a "just-in-time job" is a task that is required to be done *just in time* (with the meaning as given in the Question.)